# RPC Implementation, Static methods or Instance methods with service locator

Tags: gwt, rpc, requestfactory

Attempting to decide on how to implement our RPC on the server side.
From the documentation for the google RequestFactory it tells me there is 2 ways to implement an RPC service.  http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html

"Services can be implemented on the server in one of two ways: as static methods in a type or as instance methods in a service class accompanied by a ServiceLocator"

I did a simple service using the Static methods way and worked fine, job done.  Using the service locator requires a lot more complexity. But is it that simple,  anyone know what the down side, if any,  to using static methods is ?  To me the simplest way is usually the best.  Might there be scalability issues or anything?

Thanks ...

Comment: A bit of history: initially RF only did static methods, then developers used to dependency injections (Spring or Guice) asked for instance methods, so `ServiceLocator` was introduced. `static` is kind of an anti-pattern, so many people avoid it. What's great with RF is that you can easily change your mind ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the employee example in the `RequestFactory` documentation, from the architectural point of view, does it make sense to have a class `Employee`, effectively a domain object, being responsible for persisting itself?

If you want to split those responsibilities, then the second approach is preferred, and as you said it is a bit more complex (but not that much).

Comment: I see your point. In my case it's no big deal to have domain objects persist themselves so looks like we can proceed as we were.  cheers